# Проблемы при сабмите формы Symfony

Tags: php

контороллер

```
/**
 * @Route("/customer/edit/{id}", name="customer_edit", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function edit($id, Request $request)
{
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    $form = $this->createForm(CustomerType::class, $customer);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        echo 1; die();

        //return $this->redirectToRoute('form_edit_example', ['product'=>$product->getId()]);

    }

    return $this->render('customer/edit.html.twig', ['customer' => $customer, 'form' => $form->createView()]);
    

    //$form = $this->createForm(CustomerType::class, $customer,);

    //return $this->render('customer/edit.html.twig', ['customer' => $customer, 'form' => $form->createView()]);

}
```

CustomerType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [new Length(['min' => 3])],

        ])
        ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', TextType::class)
        ->add('phoneNumber', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);

}
```

routes

```
 customer_edit:
   path: /customer/edit/{id}
   controller: App\Controller\CustomerController::edit
   methods: [GET]
```

Выпадает следующая ошибка o route found for "POST /customer/edit/29": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET).

Comment: О чем и говорит `methods: [GET]`.

Comment: Я его убрал и заработало.

Comment: Также зачем __два__ объявления роута? В аннотациях и в yml-файле.